# Why does adding a second domain for my appengine application result in an Invalid Domain error?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an appengine app hosted on mylongdomain.net

I have added a second domain to my google apps account, it's a short Palestine domain: short.ps

When I try to use the admin console to add this domain to the list of URLs for my appengine app (in admin console->more controls->App engine apps->my app name under "Add new URL") I am able to select short.ps from the dropdown list of domains.  However, when I try to add it as http://www.short.ps, I am unable to do so.  I get the error "Invalid Domain".

My domain is verified and the CNAME record is correctly pointed to GHS.GOOGLEHOSTED.COM.

Does anyone know why I am getting Invalid Domain error and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Admin console.  Apps support was completely unhelpful: "we don't support the app engine apps part of the admin console".

However, setting up a second google apps account for domain short.ps and also adding the appengine app to that account seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Secondary domain currently has lot of restrictions , one of those is secondary domain are not supported in Google AppEngine, and one cannot switch primary domains too(as of now)

link to limitations for secondary domain : https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081?hl=en

the simple solution would be to add your domain as Alias to primary domain, then point it to your AppEngine app by setting appropriate CNAME, it will work (i have personally tried it)

Comment: Does the CNAME solution allow users to browse to a URL with a path http://www.short.ps/something and have it redirect to http://www.mylongdomain.net/something?  I believe that will not work, that is why this was not a solution for me.